# i get the permissions denied error while uploading an image on the local xampp server

Tags: php, upload

the htdocs folder in xampp has the 777 permissions, i can copy alter any file manually there but uploading a file into a subfolder gives an error. my code is:

```
<?php
define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 1024 * 50);
if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {
// define constant for upload folder
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/properties/');
// replace any spaces in original filename with underscores
$file = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES['image']['name']);
// create an array of permitted MIME types
$permitted = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg','image/png');
// upload if file is OK
if (in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], $permitted)
  && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0 
  && $_FILES['image']['size'] <= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
switch($_FILES['image']['error']) {
  case 0:
    // check if a file of the same name has been uploaded
    if (!file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $file)) {
// move the file to the upload folder and rename it
$success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR $file);
} else {
$result = 'A file of the same name already exists.';
}
if ($success) {
$result = "$file uploaded successfully.";
} else {
$result = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
}
break;
case 3:
case 6:
case 7:
case 8:
$result = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
break;
case 4: 
$result = "You didn't select a file to be uploaded.";
}
} else {
$result = "$file is either too big or not an image.";
}
}
?>
```

the error i get is:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/opt/lampp/htdocs/properties/Cover.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/listprop.php on line 82
```

Answer (score 0):

check is `safe_mode` is `on` in your `php.ini`

If only the xampp folder is writable that doesn't help, you need the sub-folders writable too.

Second, just asking

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/properties/');
```

where `lampp` is shouldn't that be `xampp`? just asking (that can cause move problems too)

Comment: lampp is what the dir name is on the disk, thats how it was when i installed it.. the safe_mode is off in the php.ini, and the chmod was applied to all the subfolders along with the htdocs dir..

Comment: also, the upload_tmp_dir is not defined, the error shows its using tmp, so ive set the tmp folder with 777 permissions, but still no luck

Comment: and what does your apache log say?